# Commandline PHP script how to cause memory overflow intentionally

Tags: php, apache, nginx, command-line

What is easiest way to cause memory overflow intentionally in PHP?

It is necessary for system administrator to check if he has increased RAM on server and has allowed PHP developer to set enough limit in `php.ini`.

Comment: Can't u like just check the `memory_limit` inside `phpinfo` or with `ini_get('memory_limit')`?

Comment: I can check but limits only <br />

php -r 'echo  ini_get("memory_limit");  ini_set("memory_limit", "9999M"); echo ini_get("memory_limit");'

<br/>\n
to see the real available memory (e.g. RAM of the virtual machine) I need  that script

Answer (score 0):

```
php -r '$str = "hello world"; ini_set("memory_limit", "1024M"); while(true) { $str .= $str;}'
```

for your convenience I reformatted it:

```
$str = 'hello world'; 
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
while(true) {
    $str .= $str;
}
```